# How to get response from server after posting data using RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to post data on server using retrofit2 and rxjava2 after data posted successfully on server I want to get response from server.I am using kotlin so how can I get server response in my app.

This is what I have done so far:

**AddHero.kt**

```
class AddHero : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_hero)

    addHero.setOnClickListener {

        if(hero.text.toString().equals("")){

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Enter superhero name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else if(movie.text.toString().equals("")){

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Enter movie name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{

            saveData()
        }
    }

}

private fun saveData() {

    RetrofitClient.create().saveHero(hero.text.toString(),movie.text.toString())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe()

   }
}
```

**RetrofitClient.kt**

```
object RetrofitClient {

fun create():ApiService{

    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                       .connectTimeout(12,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                       .readTimeout(12,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                       .writeTimeout(12,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                       .build()

   val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl("https://www.example.com")
               .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
               .client(okHttpClient)
               .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    return service
   }

}
```

**ApiService.kt**

```
interface ApiService {

@POST("createHero")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun saveHero(@Field("name") name:String,
             @Field("movie") movie:String):Observable<Hero>

}
```

**Hero.kt**

```
data class Hero (

        @SerializedName("name")
        val name:String,

        @SerializedName("movie")
        val movie:String
)
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong or missing. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: So, you subscribed to the event, but you want to `doOnNext` if you are wanting to observe the response

Comment: So how can I Observe an event.

Comment: Have you looked at the RxJava docs on Observables? Something like `saveHero(..).onNext(...).subscribe()`

Comment: ``onNext()`` method is call under subscribe.

Comment: I'm not seeing that in your question

Answer (score 0):

Your `ApiService` `saveHero` function returns `Observable<Hero>`, you should get your response in subscribe(onNext, onError), like this:

```
RetrofitClient.create().saveHero(hero.text.toString(), movie.text.toString())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ hero -> Log.d("AddHeroTag", hero.toString()) },
                { error -> Log.e("AddHero", error.message, error) })
```

And don't forget to check if your object is non-null

Comment: and also don't forget to make the api call a Single because it makes no sense for it to be an Observable

Comment: I want to know why you have added ``hero.toString()`` in ``Log.d`` statement will it get response from server I am sending response like ``Data added`` from server..

Comment: I added Log just for example, you don't need it, all you have to do is check your `Hero` object for nullability and do what you want with it

Comment: @Dig If your API only returns a String, you'll need to change `Observable<Hero>` to a `Observable<String>`